# Why is it true that ${(\nabla Y)'^i}_j = {Y'^i}_{,j} + {\Gamma'^i}_{jk}Y'^k $?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I do not understand why this equation transforms as it does : ${(\nabla Y)'^i}_j = {Y'^i}_{,j} + {\Gamma'^i}_{jk}Y'^k $

Could someone give me a detailed explanation of why this is true please?
I understand that ${(\nabla Y)^i}_j = {Y^i}_{,j} + {\Gamma^i}_{jk}Y^k$. But it is not clear to me why when transforming the $(1,1)$ tensor, $\nabla Y$, to a new co-ordinate system, that the components change as in the RHS of the equation above.

Help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Note : It is hinted below in the comments that ${(\nabla Y)'^i}_j = {(\nabla Y')^i}_j$. If this is true, please will you make clear to me why we can allow this please!

Comment: makes no sense.. you should be writing $(\nabla Y)^i_j={Y^i}_{,j}+{\Gamma^i}_{jk}Y^k$

Comment: Yes. Sorry. That was a typo. Can you help with the amended version?

Comment: why do you insist in using primes? that obscures your understanding

Comment: Primes just indicate a change in co-ordinate system.

Comment: ok.. if the qantities $Y'^i$ gives you a rank one tensor, then ${(\nabla Y')^i}_j$ allows you to construct a rank two (mixed) tensor

Comment: Why is the prime inside the bracket here?

Comment: allow me a nuance

Comment: Do you mean to say you are representing the same thing? I.e that ${(\nabla Y)'^i}_j = {(\nabla Y')^i}_j$. If so, then this is my issue. As I then I see potential inconsistency. As we will then be switching to a different co-ordinate system in Y too.

Comment: Of course I'm sure there is no inconsistency and the two notations match up seamlessly. But I do not see how they do.

Comment: well, think only in ${{(\nabla Y)'}^i}_j$ meanwhile

Comment: Okay, I will do. Are you able to tell me why the above transformation holds true?

Comment: in $(\nabla Y)'$ you gotta use Leibniz's rule.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate this in an answer below please. I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and so I think I just need someone to spell the details out now. I would be really grateful if you took a little time to show me this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\nabla Y)^i_j=\frac{d}{dt}\left({Y^i}_{,j}+{\Gamma^i}_{jk}Y^k\right)$$
$$ =\frac{d}{dt}{Y^i}_{,j}+\frac{d}{dt}\left({\Gamma^i}_{jk}Y^k\right)$$
$$ =\frac{d}{dt}{Y^i}_{,j}+\frac{d}{dt}\left({\Gamma^i}_{jk}\right)Y^k+{\Gamma^i}_{jk}\frac{d}{dt}\left({Y^i}\right)$$
et cetera.

Last edit:

The term $\frac{d}{dt}({Y^i}_{,j})$ needs to be processed with $\frac{d}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^s}\frac{dx^s}{dt}$, then giving you $\frac{d}{dt}({Y^i}_{,j})={Y^i}_{,js}\frac{dx^s}{dt}$, where $x^s$ are the coordinated functions.

So $$({{(\nabla Y)}^i}_j)'={Y^i}_{,js}\frac{dx^s}{dt}+({\Gamma^i}_{jk})'Y^k+{\Gamma^i}_{jk}({Y^k})'.$$

Comment: hope it helps now

Comment: Sorry. Could you spell it out exactly please. My brain is fried at this point. I do in general believe hints are the best form of learning. But right now I just need all the details spelt out. This is killing me.

Comment: the hint is in purely math language which hypothetically would help better, anyway you gotta relax

Comment: I'm afraid I am not seeing it from your hint though. I honestly think I just need spelt out.

Comment: and I afraid almost no people upvote me XD

Comment: Haha. I don't have my account verified yet. Are you saying you'll answer in full detail if I do?

Comment: mmmh.. only you think a little more and then you gonna get thru.. i finally say